# Is it possible to separate part of a match in RegEx within RegEx?

Tags: regex

**So I've come across an issue while using RegEx**.

As typical, my code is often, just, an absolute mess! I realized I could probably clean it up with RegEx.

So I went on to make a Minecraft color formatter for a stupid project of mine, which is a completely custom server software that is based on TypeScript.

As I was making it, I soon realized, that the way I did it - guess what! Doesn't work. It only returns **one match**. Here's an example of what I get:

```
String: &#ff5c5chello there! this is just a &#aa5cfftest!
Matches: [ "&#ff5c5chello there! this is just a &#aa5cfftest!" ]
```

And what I expect is:

```
String: &#ff5c5chello there! this is just a &#aa5cfftest!
Matches: [ "&#ff5c5chello there! this is just a", "&#aa5cfftest!" ]
```

If it isn't clear, what I want to separate off is &#(hex code), as an example: `&#ffffff`

The regex I used is `/(&#[0-9a-f]{6}.*)*/g`

Does anyone know how to do this? Or is this even possible with RegEx?

Edit: Another thing that I must mention is that the start, if it doesn't start with something like `&#(hex code)`, must be another separate match! Example:

```
String: I am the &#5cff5cComputer &#4cee4cMan
Matches: [ "I am the ", "&#5cff5cComputer ", "&#4cee4cMan" ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
.+?(?=(?:&#|$))
```

You can play with it and have an explanation of how it works in the following link: https://regex101.com/r/vBUSi9/1

Comment: Thanks! This really helped - I just made a slight tweak to it, as I needed for the whole hex code to match and if it's not a hex code - just count it as the last match. Here's my final regex: `.+?(?=(?:&#[0-9a-fk-or]{6}|$))`

Comment: whoops, messed it up! I got a little confused as Minecraft has their own basic color codes like &e and etc..

here's the actual final regex: `.+?(?=(?:&#[0-9a-f]{6}|$))`